# PyMongo Only include field in document if value is not a NaN

Tags: python, mongodb, insert, pymongo, nan

I have a significant amount of data that needs to be inserted into my MongoDB database using PyMongo. The data I have is currently stored in flat files and is sparse (i.e. many of the individual values are NaN). In Mongo DB I would like to not insert fields if values are NaN but I'm not sure how to do that (I should point out I'm new to both MongoDB and Python).

My insert startement looks something like this

```
            strategy.insert_many([
            {
                "strategyId": strategyInfo[stratIndex][ID],
                "strategyName": strategyInfo[stratIndex][NAME],
                "date": dates[i],
                "time": thisTime,
                "aum": stratAum[i],
                "return":0.0,
                "commission":0.0,
                "slippage":0.0,
                "basket":[{
                    "assetId": assets[m][ASSETID],
                    "order": orders[i, m],
                    "expiry": expiry[i, m],
                    "price": prices[i, m],
                    "ePrice": eprices[i, m]     <<<Don't include line if eprices[i,m] is a NaN
                }
                    for m in range(len(assets))
                ]
            }
        ], False)
```

It's easy enough to check to see if one of my value's is NaN using `math.isnan()` but I can't figure out how to leave the entire field blank if that is the case.

Comment: How about fixing your data first. What's is the source of your data?

Comment: The data is internally generated. There is nothing wrong with it. The missing values are deliberate.

Answer (score 0):

> It's easy enough to check to see if one of my value's is NaN using `math.isnan()` but I can't figure out how to leave the entire field blank if that is the case.

Based on your example code, you can do the following instead:

```
# Create a strategy document. 
# This is inside of a loop where variable `i` is known, similar to your example. 
doc = {
  "strategyId": strategyInfo[stratIndex][ID],
  "strategyName": strategyInfo[stratIndex][NAME],
  "date": dates[i],
  "time": thisTime,
  "aum": stratAum[i],
  "return":0.0,
  "commission":0.0,
  "slippage":0.0
}
baskets = []
for m in range(len(assets)):
    basket = {
        "assetId": assets[m][ASSETID],
        "order": orders[i, m],
        "expiry": expiry[i, m],
        "price": prices[i, m],
    }
    if not math.isnan(eprice[i, m]):
        basket["ePrice"] = eprice[i, m]
    baskets.append(basket)

# You can also add a filter here to make sure `baskets` array is not null.
doc["basket"] = baskets
docs.append(doc)
```

Which essentially separating the making your document and the database insertion.

You can then use [insert_many()](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many):

```
strategy.insert_many(docs, False)
```

You can also wrap the `insert_many` in a try/except to detect database insert error, which should be different error handling from your document creation error.